# How to hide edges to hidden nodes when collapsing visNetwork

Tags: r, visnetwork

I am trying to collapse a visNetwork graph using the `collapse` argument. However, the edges connected to hidden nodes are not collapsed correctly and remain visible. See minimal example:

```
library(visNetwork)
library(magrittr)
nodes <- data.frame(id = letters[1:7],
                    label = letters[1:7],
                    hidden = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                    x = c(1, rep(200, 3), rep(400, 3)),
                    y = c(rep(200, 2), 100, 300, 100, 300, 200))
edges <- data.frame(from = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b'),
                    to = c('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'))
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visPhysics(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  visNodes(shape = 'circle') %>%
  visOptions(collapse = list(enabled = TRUE, keepCoord = TRUE))
```

When double clicking on node b I would like all outgoing edges to be hidden, however those connected to hidden nodes c and d remain visible. Is this not possible in visNetwork currently or is there a way to fix this?